# Why is bookdown not numbering the figures in one chapter but it does in the others?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Why does the figure numbering break in my [chapter 3](https://spaceshiptitanic.manborgconsulting.com/handle-missing-data.html) but it works in the other chapters? As far as I can see, the chunks are named correctly and all figures have captions.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/MoonCastle85/SpaceshipTitanicBook/blob/main/02-handle-missing.Rmd).

Comment: You should simplify your document until it is small enough to post here in its entirety.  Quite likely when doing that you'll discover what the issue is and won't need to post, but if not, someone here might spot it.  Linking to external data is no use to anyone else and goes against the spirit (and maybe rules, for all I know) of StackOverflow, because your link could disappear at any time.

Comment: @user2554330 You're right but since the output can be affected by something global when using bookdown, I didn't know where the error was so this seemed like the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html):

> If you want to cross-reference figures or tables generated from a code chunk, please make sure the chunk label only contains alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9), slashes (/), or dashes (-).

Your chunk labels contain underscores.

Comment: Thanks, I would've never found this!

Comment: That's my bad. You are not the only one who has been confused by this problem.